# android upload progressbarr not working

Tags: php, android, android-networking, android-progressbar

I'm a beginner in Android programming and I was tryinh to upload an image to a server.
I found some code here on stackoverflow, I adjusted it and it still doesn't work.

The problem is my image still won't upload.

**edit I solved the problem**, I had no rights on the folder on the server.
Now I have a new problem. the progresbarr doesn't work. it keeps saying 0 % transmitted

does anyone sees an error in my code?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class PreviewActivity extends Activity {

/** The captured image file. Get it's path from the starting intent */
private File mImage;

public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH = "extraImagePath"

/** Log tag */
private static final String TAG = "DFH";

/** Progress dialog id */
private static final int UPLOAD_PROGRESS_DIALOG = 0;
private static final int UPLOAD_ERROR_DIALOG = 1;
private static final int UPLOAD_SUCCESS_DIALOG = 2;


/** Handler to confirm button */
private Button mConfirm;

/** Handler to cancel button */
private Button mCancel;

/** Uploading progress dialog */
private ProgressDialog mDialog;


/**
 * Called when the activity is created
 *
 * We load the captured image, and register button callbacks
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.preview);

    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

    // Import image
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String imagePath = extras.getString(FotoActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH);
    Log.d("DFHprev", imagePath);
    mImage = new File(imagePath);
    if (mImage.exists()) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        loadImage(mImage);
    }

    registerButtonCallbacks();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

/**
 * Register callbacks for ui buttons
 */
protected void registerButtonCallbacks() {
    // Cancel button callback
    mCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.preview_send_cancel);
    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PreviewActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });

    // Confirm button callback
    mConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.preview_send_confirm);
    mConfirm.setEnabled(true);
    mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new UploadImageTask().execute(mImage);
        }
    });
}



/**
 * Initialize the dialogs
 */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
    case UPLOAD_PROGRESS_DIALOG:
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.progress_dialog_title_connecting));
        return mDialog;


    case UPLOAD_ERROR_DIALOG:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.upload_error_title)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setMessage(R.string.upload_error_message)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.retry), new          DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        PreviewActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();

    case UPLOAD_SUCCESS_DIALOG:
        AlertDialog.Builder success = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        success.setTitle(R.string.upload_success_title)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setMessage(R.string.upload_success_message)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.success), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        PreviewActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });
        return success.create();

    default:
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Prepare the progress dialog
 */
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    switch(id) {
    case UPLOAD_PROGRESS_DIALOG:
        mDialog.setProgress(0);
        mDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.progress_dialog_title_connecting));
    }
}

/**
 * Load the image file into the imageView
 *
 * @param image
 */
protected void loadImage(File image) {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath());
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview_image);
    view.setImageBitmap(bm);
}

/**
 * Asynchronous task to upload file to server
 */
class UploadImageTask extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, Boolean> {

    /** Upload file to this url */
    private static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://www.xxxx.x/xxxx/fotos";

    /** Send the file with this form name */
    private static final String FIELD_FILE = "file";


    /**
     * Prepare activity before upload
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        mConfirm.setEnabled(false);
        mCancel.setEnabled(false);
        showDialog(UPLOAD_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    }

    /**
     * Clean app state after upload is completed
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        mConfirm.setEnabled(true);
        mDialog.dismiss();

        if (result) {
            showDialog(UPLOAD_SUCCESS_DIALOG);
        } else {
            showDialog(UPLOAD_ERROR_DIALOG);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(File... image) {
        return doFileUpload(image[0], "UPLOAD_URL");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        if (values[0] == 0) {
            mDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.progress_dialog_title_uploading));
        }

        mDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }


    private boolean doFileUpload(File file, String uploadUrl) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = file.getPath();
        String urlServer = "http://www.xxxx.x/xxxx/upload.php";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";

        // log pathtoourfile
        Log.d("DFHinUpl", pathToOurFile);

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        int sentBytes = 0;
        long fileSize = file.length();

        // log filesize
        String files= String.valueOf(fileSize);
        String buffers= String.valueOf(maxBufferSize);
        Log.d("fotosize",files);
        Log.d("buffers",buffers);

        try
        {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        sentBytes += bufferSize;
        publishProgress((int)(sentBytes * 100 / fileSize));

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();



        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        try {
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            return responseCode == 200;
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.e("DFHUPLOAD", "Upload file failed: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DFHUPLOAD", "Upload file failed: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String msg= ex.getMessage();
        Log.d("DFHUPLOAD", msg);
        }
        return true;
}

}
}
```

the PHP code that handles this upload is following:

```
  <?php
 $date=getdate();

      $urldate=$date['year'].$date['month'].$date['month'].$date['hours'].$date['minutes'].$date[     'seconds'];
 $target_path  = "./";
 $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . $urldate;
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
  echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
  " has been uploaded";
 } else{
  echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
 }
 ?>
```

would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: Hmm there's a lot to test here. I think this question needs to be broken down into smaller ones. One thing, you are loading the image into a view and showing it in your activity. Does that work?

Now, in the php.. something is missing, normally that $_FILES var will come from a POST GET; in your case a listener to some port. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: the file upload works now. the file is showing correctly in an imageview. and the PHP code also works. it was just something with the permissions. i've set the folders permission to 777 and it worked. The only problem left now is the progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

Views are not supposed to be accessible in onCreate(). Try to move some code to onStart().

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    mImage = new File(imagePath);
    if (mImage.exists()) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        loadImage(mImage);
    }

    registerButtonCallbacks();
}
```

I haven't run the code so I don't know if there are other defects as well.

Comment: the buttons did work, but thanks for your response. now I only need to make the progressbar follow the file upload

Comment: you're right. thanks to you, I found out it is sufficient to call setContentView() first.